# 360/Spherical Images in ImageViewer

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way of implementing 360/spherical images using ImageViewer or a different component in CN1? Currently I'm using ImageViewer as an image carousel for regular images and would like to expand to panoramas and image spheres.

Comment: Not at this time. I think it shouldn't be too hard to create a viewer for that but there is nothing builtin.